# How to collect an SNCF ticket abroad?

Tags: trains, tickets, eurostar, sncf

I bought Eurostar tickets from Utrecht to Paris from sncf-connect.com, and imported those in the SNCF Connect app on my phone.

For the Rotterdam - Paris section, there is a QR code, but for Utrecht - Rotterdam, it instructs me to collect the tickets from a ticket machine before departure.

This is explained in more detail on the *how to collect your ticket* page in the app, where it says you can use either an SNCF ticket machine, or go to an SNCF train station.

There is no option to print the ticket.

Is there any way to collect my ticket in the Netherlands (preferably in Utrecht)?

Comment: It looks like the Utretch to Rotterdam is on NS, you may need to go to a NS ticket office to get the tickets

Comment: @NicolasFormichella do you know where to get more information about that? I know it is NS, but the tickets were bought through sncf

Comment: SNCF connect is a pain to deal with, first I suggest you to contact NS and find out if they can create your ticket, if they can't, try [contacting](https://www.sncf-connect.com/aide/contact) SNCF Connect... If everything fails, you may want to bite the bullet and get a separate NS ticket for that journey (12€20)

Comment: SNCF connect has no clue even about trains. They will tell you that you need to board the Utrecht to Rotterdam train 5 minutes before departure (which is nonsensical) and that you have to be at Rotterdam for the Eurostar to Paris an hour in advance, which is also nonsens.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I am pretty sure they didn't change the programming after Thalys and Eurostar merger (With OG Eurostar requiring you to be at boarding an hour early due to border formalities)

Comment: The fact that they can't be bothered to fix this (this problem has been around for a while) says something...

Comment: [This page](https://support-en.nsinternational.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15779/~/passing-the-gates-at-ns-stations-%C2%BB-general-information) shows that you can enter and leave the station with EuroStar tickets, assuming the ticket you bought is valid (and if checked the conductor will be able to check/verify it, you have all you need to complete your trip

Comment: @ROIMaison That page is about being able to pass the gates at a station. I assume that the Eurostar ticket (Rotterdam to Paris) will only allow that in Rotterdam. And I don't think the Eurostar ticket is valid on domestic trains (but I'll need to check that to be certain)

Comment: @Berend, if you bought a ticket from Utrecht to Paris, you can travel from Utrecht to Paris (regardless of where you bought it). If you're worried about passing the gates in Utrecht, you can request an email with a QR code [here](https://www.ns.nl/en/travel-information/passageproducten/keycard.html).
But best to contact NS via chat. If you figure out the answer please post it here for others to learn :)

Comment: @ROIMaison I'm not worried about passing the gates, it's just that On the Utrecht - Rotterdam section I won't be able to show a valid ticket.

Comment: @Berend, if SNCF is not helpful, you could try and contact NS international. They are usually quite responsive. You can ask them if the ticket you have is valid on NS trains, I suggest you contact them via chat/email so you have a document you can show the conductor if there are doubts.

Comment: @ROIMaison NS will tell: You bought this ticket from SNCF, so you need to take this up with SNCF. And SCNF will tell: We warned you in advance that you would have to pick this up in France. You could at that time have decided not to pruchase.

Comment: @KristvanBesien You're correct, I reached out to NS international, and they said that since they cannot 'see' the ticket, they cannot say anything about its validity on Dutch trains. Knowing it was bought through SNCF (in combination with a Eurostar trip) alone is not enough.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Except SNCF didn't warn about that. Well, maybe somewhere in the fine print, but nowhere obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way for you to collect this ticket. SNCF is not able to produce electronic tickets for domestic Dutch trains. The same problem also often turns up when buying tickets for other countries on SNCF.

This is one of the reasons why it is often best to buy your train ticket from the national railway of the country where the trip starts. Had you bought this on nsinternational.com you would not have run in to this issue.

See if you can cancel that part of the trip, and buy a trip for Utrecht - Rotterdam in the Netherlands.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but not entirely surprising either. I think that *technically* they could do it, I mean, Deutsche Bahn can, so why not SNCF. Wether they want to is a different question of course ;-) I'm still waiting for a reply from SNCF, but they're slow to respond.

Comment: The will needs to exist of course. And NS, DB, NMBS, OBB, SBB etc... all use the TSI standard for ticketing. SNCF of course does not.

Comment: For the Netherlands using the NSInternational website often *isn't* the best way to get tickets; it's horrifically slow when you want to compare multiple dates. DB and ÖBB (for their Nightjet) have websites which are much easier to search tickets from, and their tickets work in the Netherlands. It really depends on the operator.

Comment: Yes, you can use DB and OBB etc... This because those countries all follow the TSI standard for e tickets...

Comment: @Berend "*I mean, Deutsche Bahn can, so why not SNCF.*" The DB refuses to sell me tickets whose start and end point are in the same foreign country (that is, any country but germany), such as your Utrecht-Rotterdam section. It lets you buy tickets from a border town in Germany to anywhere in NL, but not from just across the border in NL to anywhere in NL. Is what what you mean with that it can print tickets valid in NL: they have the ability but not the policy to take away customers from Dutch operators?

Comment: @Luc No, I meant they can sell international tickets that include a domestic section. In my question, I mentioned the entire journey is from Utrecht to Paris, so SNCF can sell that (never mind you can't get the ticket). DB can sell a ticket to Berlin that for instance includes a local journey from Utrecht to Amersfoort, and they do.

Comment: I have bought Amsterdam into France tickets from the SNCF but you have to get self print or app shown tickets, or give them time (and I think money) to send paper tickets to your address.

Comment: @luc: DB does not sell tickets for domestic Dutch journeys, but NMBS, OBB, and SBB for example do. However you will end up paying more than when you buy directly from NS, so it is not very useful. Which is maybe why DB just doesn't do it. 
Another difference is that DB sells tickets for a "relation", whereas SNCF nowadays sells tickets for trains. So Utrecht - Paris ends up being two tickets, whereas Utrecht - Hamburg for example is one ticket.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Krist's answer, here's the response I got from SNCF:

> The withdrawal for this ticket referenced XXXXXX can only be printed on a self service kiosk in a French or Luxembourg train station. The SNCF does not have the possibility to give you an e-ticket with the foreign trains.
>
> If you cannot print it in a French train station, I invite you to, first, book a new ticket at the station or on the official website of the country. Do not cancel those tickets, you might have cancellation fees.
> Then, to request a refund, please click here: https://alc.cx/vsiva